# Accessing the reference of a child class from an abstract parent

Tags: java, android

I have an abstract class. It contains a private class field. In one of the methods in the private class field, I need to refer to `this` of whatever child class extends the abstract class.

```
public abstract class ActivityCrazy extends Activity {
 private class FoolClickedButton implements OnClickListener {
  public void onClick(View v) {
   startActivity(
    new Intent(
     IMPLEMENTER_OF_ABSTRACT_CLASS.this,
     AnotherClass.class
   )
  }
 }
}
```

How do I properly do this?

Before ActivityCrazy was not an abstract class, so I could use `ActivitySpecific.this`. But now I realized that many classes need the same private FoolClickedButton, so I created this abstract class. The problem is that FoolClickedButton's onClick method must refer to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Before ActivityCrazy was not an abstract class, so I could use
>   ActivitySpecific.this. But now I realized that many classes need the
>   same private FoolClickedButton, so I created this abstract class. The
>   problem is that FoolClickedButton's onClick method must refer to
>   itself.

Have you tried just using `ActivityCrazy.this`?

It should work, and reference the actual instantiated concrete subclass object.